# Как в php выровнять строки по длине

Tags: php, строки, telegram

Есть разные строки, которые отправляются одним сообщением. Хочу сделать в виде примитивной таблицы, напр:

```
параметр1      4
парам2         5
парамммммммм3  7
```

Использую html пробелы, т.к. в сообщениях доступен только один пробел. Проблема в том, что все символы разной длины, и просто str_pad не подойдет. Всегда присутствует сдвиг вправо/влево. Есть ли какая-то функция, которая это учитывает?

Comment: есть моноширинный шрифт, который все символы одинаковые делает. но вообще не ясно в каком виде вы это отправляете

Comment: Нет возможности изменить шрифт, к сожалению. Это сообщение с телеграм-бота

Comment: @shumik_UA а как все эти параметры передаются в код? array или в переменных?

Comment: в пользовательских сообщениях можно бэктики использовать для форматирования текста как кода с использованием моноширинного шрифта. в вашем случае, это не применимо?

Comment: @adudnik.ru по очереди заганяю в функцию строки *параметр1,парам2 и т.д *, и передаю так же условную длину строки, которую надо сформировать

Comment: @teran к сожалению надо сохранить красоту текста, без лишних символов

Comment: @shumik_UA Думаю проще всего ставить в начале значения, а затем уже выводить названия. Длину значения просчитать элементарно и цифры ближе всего по длине в пикселях к пробелу. Т.е. у вас будет псевдотаблица где в начале значения, а потом уже заголовки param, parametr и т.д.

Comment: @adudnik.ru идея хорошая, но я бы все-таки хотел найти способ выравнивать символы

Comment: @shumik_UA, ок, тогда так: считаете длину каждого литера в пикселях и формируете из этого массив (натурально в браузере считаете включая пробел). Далее считаете в пикселях длину самой длинной строки. Все последующие строки приводите к этому значению увеличивая на нужное количество пробелов `(длина нужной строки в пикселях - длина текущей строки в пикселях)/длину пробела в пикселях = количество пробелов, которое требуется добавить`. Добавляете нужное количество пробелов. О кроссбраузерности/кросс платформенности речи идти не может.

Comment: @shumik_UA вариант 2 - прикидываете изначально длину самого длинного параметра (условно 15 литеров), далее через mb_strlen() смотрите длину строки и добавляете пробелов чтобы стало в сумме 15.

Comment: @shumik_UA что-то вроде [этого](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b58dff6a1463451e07387ffcd35f919a0cbded05) ?

Comment: @shumik_UA вариант 3, если количество параметров конечно - поиграйтесь и просчитайте к какому сколько пробелов добавлять для более-менее ровной таблицы (поиграйтесь с названиями) и просто запишите названия параметров с изначально правильным количеством пробелов.

Comment: @adudnik.ru он и так добавляет пробелы до нужной длины. Проблема в том, что шрифт не моноширинный, пробелами так физически не подогнать в принципе.

Comment: @teran да я понимаю. Как говорится лучшее из возможного (поминки).

Comment: @shumik_UA кстати в телеграмме можно добавлять тег ссылки `<a href="#">` попробуй к нему добавить style вот так `<a href="#" style="width:250px;">параметр 1</a>` - вдруг сработает, тогда можно будет легко задать нужную длину в пикселях. А не вот это вот всё.

Comment: @adudnik.ru стили добавлять нельзя

Comment: @shumik_UA ну тогда самое аккуратное внешне - это сначала значения, потом параметры или вообще отказаться от идеи таблиц и делать через запятую.

Comment: Омг всем спасибо, покопался в документации - можно поставить тэг моноширного текста.